# after adding CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS curl doesn't send anything

Tags: c++, firebase, curl, timeout

I have a while loop, and inside that loop I send a PUT request into google firebase REST api. It works very well, but if I want to fasten things up (the while loop waits for the curl response every round of the loop which is very slow sometimes, over 200ms), I'm trying to add the `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` and set it to a low 1 millisecond.

TLDR;
after adding line

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1L);`

My curl does not send anything to the server anymore. Or does the server somehow force the client to receive the returning value from the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tell curl to fail the operation if it isn't completed within **1 millisecond**. Not many requests are completed that quickly, especially not if you're using DNS or just use connections over the Internet.

So yes, most transfers will then just return `CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT` (28) with no content.

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me a way to actually make curl not wait for the response? Or should I just increment the timeout to some 50 milliseconds for example?

Comment: I already tried to raise the treshold to 30ms, it still isn't updating the data on my server. I think it should get the data out and moving from my program in 30ms, otherwise I would consider the library plain slow and crappy.

Comment: HTTP is a request/response protocol. You can't tell curl to not wait for an HTTP response. The data has to be removed from the socket, especially if you are sending multiple PUTs requests over a single TCP connection. But you can make curl discard any response data it receives and not output it anywhere, at least.

Comment: You're free to consider the library how you want. The law of physics is however tricky to combat and 30 ms is also a very short time if you're connecting to sites over the Internet.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes I know, but does it mean that if I shut down the connection from my end after let's say 30 milliseconds, the data would not arrive to the server even though it has left my machine already? I just want to send the data, no matter what the response is. Like "fire and forget".

Comment: curl will of course do as much as it can up until the point you stop it (with the timeout) but 30 milliseconds is not a lot of time

Comment: @DanielStenberg I understand your point, but I'm meaning that I would just resume my program straight after the data has left my machine. As I described in the last comment I wrote. I don't really care about the response. edit: ah you responsed already. I will try again with 100ms timeout and will report back how it worked out!

Comment: but you also don't know if anything was sent in that time, not even if curl manged to resolve the name or connect TCP/TLS etc

Comment: That's true... I didn't even think about the TLS auth.. Do you have any workarounds for this to fasten things up?

Comment: Sure, move the server closer to the client. Don't use DNS. Don't do HTTPS. And use TCP Fast Open.

Comment: I guess I need to write my own REST api for my webserver, using google is a pain at least latency wise. Thanks for your help @DanielStenberg !

Comment: @JussiHietanen unless you write a low level network monitoring driver, there is no way to know when your outbound data actually leaves the machine. When you send data, it is buffered in the kernel first, and the kernel sends it in the background on its own time. If you close the socket before the kernel has flushed the buffer, it might not be sent at all. At the very least, you should delay closing the socket until you receive the first byte of the response.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of CURL.

If your timeout setting is less than 1s, it will directly return an error.

Solution is:

```
curl_easy_setopt(conn, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
```

`conn` is the pointer of CURL, e.g.:

```
CURL *conn = NULL;
curl_easy_setopt(conn, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
```